# Selecting text only following certain elements using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping

As shown in the following snippet I have multiple divs of text where there is a bolded portion, then a line break then a piece of text. I can find() the bolded portion but how can I get only the text portions which follow the linebreak after the bolded portions with javascript/jquery?

```
<div class="thecontent">
any amount of text or html elements before
<b>
    the bolded text
</b>
<br>
the text I need together with the bolded text which can contain other html
elements apart from line breaks and bolded blocks
<br>
<b>
    posibility of more bolded and text couples further in the div
</b>
<br>
and some more text to go with the bolded text
</div>
```

There can be multiple bolded portions and text couples in a single div and the pieces of text needed either end with a line break, another bolded portion or the end of the div. There may be other html elements like `<a href>` in the text blocks.

I can get the contents of the `<b> </b>` with `.find('b')` and I've tried using `nodeType == 3` to select the text node but that only gets me all the text.

Unfortunately I cannot change the html of the page. Does anyone have the solution? Thanks in advance :)

As requested the input will be bolded blocks a linebreak and the text following them. I need the text following them up until a line break or another bolded portion.

The output would be the bolded text in one variable and the text following after the linebreak but until the next linebreak or bold element in another variable.

So output for the html example is: `the bolded text` + `the text I need together with the bolded text which can contain other html
    elements apart from line breaks and bolded blocks`

and `posibility of more bolded and text couples further in the div` + `and some more text to go with the bolded text`

Comment: I'm unable to understand your question, you want to get text content that is _not_ bold (within `<b> </b>`) but is still within `div.thecontent`?

Comment: I'm aiming to pair the bolded section with the text after it (up until the next line break or next bolded section)

Comment: Why don't you just divide your div into smaller containers (like `<div>`or `<span>`), each of them containing coherent text parts you want to filter?

Comment: @Joe could you make your question simple to understand?

Comment: @Joe, can you create a simple actual input and expected output example?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I've tried to make the question easier to understand and added expected input and output.

Comment: Updated again with a better output example :)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i don't think there's a really easy way of getting all the nodes and seperating them etc. but it sure is possible. Since I have no idea what you intend to do with the text, i made a neat little object containing everything that should be easier to work with, or you can change the code to fit your needs:

```
var elem    = $('.thecontent').get(0).childNodes,
    content = {},
    i = 0;

for (key in elem) {
    var type = elem[key].tagName ? elem[key].tagName : 'text';
    content[i] = {};
    content[i][type] = elem[key].tagName == 'B' ? $(elem[key]).text() : elem[key].nodeValue;
    i++;
}

console.log( content );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/3h5Vn/)

This returns:

```
{"0": {"text" : "any amount of text or html elements before"},
 "1": {"B"    : "the bolded text"},
 "2": {"text" : "\n"}, //also returns newlines
 "3": {"BR"   : null},
 "4": {"text" : "the text I need together with the bolded text which can contain other html elements apart from line breaks and bolded blocks"},
 "5": {"BR"   : null},
 "6": {"text" : "\n"},
 "7": {"B"    : " posibility of more bolded and text couples further in the div"},
 "8": {"text" : "\n"},
 "9": {"BR"   : null},
 "10":{"text" : "and some more text to go with the bolded text"},
}
```

You can filter this based on line number (starting with zero), tagnames, text content, or anything else you need ?

Comment: Thanks! This is a great help, I can just loop through the array.

Comment: You're welcome. It should make it easier to work with, as you can atleast select each piece of text from a line number or tagname, and the code shows how to get them, so you could change that as well if you don't need an object, but would rather do something with the returned text immediately.